# send data from silverlight to asp.net (or php?) when the user click on a button

Tags: asp.net, .net, silverlight, events, event-handling

If I click on a button of my Silverlight app, another third-party web app must gets some data.

My experience, until now, has been to create web service functions that you can call when you need, but in this case I have to give the possibility to the customer to "handle the click event on the button". In the actual case the third-party app is ASP.Net, but, if it were possible, I would like to do something portable.

Before to start with some crazy idea that will comes in my mind, I would ask: How would you do that?

Pileggi

Comment: This is a very broad question that can lead to very broad answers: WOuld you be so kind to post the specific code you achieved until now and narrow down to a specific detail of your problem?

Comment: As a general point, I would recommend all calls to 3rd party sites/services originate from your server, not the Silverlight client. *The only exception to this would be something like SEO tracking links (which you would generate on-the-fly on the SL client)*

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne: ok for a broad answare

Answer (score 1):

I  Use This Class To Create And Post a Form Dynamically

```
public class PassData
  {
    public static PassData Default = new PassData();

      public void Send(string strUrl, Dictionary<string, object> Parameters, string ContainerClientID = "divContainer")
      {
        var obj = HtmlPage.Document.GetElementById(ContainerClientID);
        if (obj != null)
        {
          HtmlElement divContainer = obj as HtmlElement;
          ClearContent((HtmlElement)divContainer);

          HtmlElement form = HtmlPage.Document.CreateElement("form");
          form.SetAttribute("id", "frmPostData");
          form.SetAttribute("name", "frmPostData");
          form.SetAttribute("target", "_blank");
          form.SetAttribute("method", "POST");
          form.SetAttribute("action", strUrl);

          if (Parameters != null)
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in Parameters)
              {
                HtmlElement hidElement = HtmlPage.Document.CreateElement("input");
                hidElement.SetAttribute("name", item.Key);
                hidElement.SetAttribute("value", item.Value.ToString());
                form.AppendChild(hidElement);
              }

          divContainer.AppendChild(form);
          form.Invoke("submit");

          ClearContent((HtmlElement)divContainer);
        }
      }

      private void ClearContent(System.Windows.Browser.HtmlElement obj)
      {
        foreach (HtmlElement item in obj.Children)
        {
          obj.RemoveChild(item);
        }
      }


  }
```

divContainer is id of a div in html

Comment: yeah, but how the final customer can handle the click on the silverlight app?